# assign looped regression rsquared to object

Tags: python, pandas, function, scikit-learn

I have a function with a regression loop built in. I want to assign the rsquareds from each iteration to an object that I can print out later.

here's part of the function (including the regression) for brevity:

```
cuts = [stats, stats_po, stats_ic, stats_id, stats_h, stats_a, stats_bos, stats_bkn, stats_nyk, stats_phi, stats_tor, stats_chi, stats_cle, stats_det, stats_ind, stats_mil, stats_den, stats_min, stats_okc, stats_por, stats_uta, stats_gsw, stats_lac, stats_lal, stats_phx, stats_sac, stats_atl, stats_cha, stats_mia, stats_orl, stats_was, stats_dal, stats_hou, stats_mem, stats_nop, stats_sas, stats_o1, stats_o2, stats_d1, stats_d2, stats_l25]

def process_cuts(c):
  c = c.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
  n = c.team.str.rsplit(" ",n=1, expand=True)
  c['city'] = n[0]
  c['team_name']=n[1]
  c['team_name']=c['team_name'].str.replace('Trailblazers','Blazers')
  c['team_name']=c['team_name'].str.replace('Bobcats','Hornets')
  for z in ['Points','Steals','Blocks','Assists','OReb','DefReb','Turnovers','FieldGoals','ThreeShots','FTP', 'Fouls','FTMiss','FGMiss','FreeThrows']:
    y = mergered[z]
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
    coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
    print(coeff_df)
    y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
    from sklearn import metrics
    rsquared = 'Rsquared:' + ' ' + z, metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_pred)

cuts_diffs = list(map(process_cuts, cuts))
```

I want to store the rsquareds for each y and print them out for each data cut.

appreciate your help

Comment: Tuck them in a list.  `rsquareds = []` ... `rsquareds.append(rsquared)`.

Comment: hi @TimRoberts I tried this but that only spits out the rsquared for the last element in the for loop into the list

Comment: You have to put the `rsquareds = []` before the loop starts.  It's the container into which you shove the entries.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I tried that just before you responded !! thank you! it worked